# ¿Mejor manera de expresar si un valor u otro es verdad?

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayudar en escribir esto de una mejor manera:

```
get tieneDiezDispositivos(): boolean {
  const dispositivos = this.cuentaDispositivos >= 10 || (this.esUnaBusquedaDeDispositivos && this.cuentaDispositivos >= 1)
  const sub = this.subTipo.length >= 10 || (this.esUnaBusquedaDeDispositivos && this.subTipo.length >= 1)
  if (dispositivos) {
    return true;
  }
  if (sub) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Esto antes era un solo boleano con la linea de cuentaDispositivos, pero estoy tratando de agregarle la secunda linea de subTipo. Al comienzo hice una linea larga the return conectandolos con && pero despues intente lo que ven arriba, pero no me parece bien.

Otra manera que se me ocurre es:

```
get tieneDiezDispositivos(): boolean {
  const dispositivos = this.cuentaDispositivos >= 10 || (this.esUnaBusquedaDeDispositivos && this.cuentaDispositivos >= 1)
  const sub = this.subTipo.length >= 10 || (this.esUnaBusquedaDeDispositivos && this.subTipo.length >= 1)
  if (dispositivos || sub) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar ternarios para simplificar tu condicional:

```
get tieneDiezDispositivos(): boolean {
  const dispositivos = this.cuentaDispositivos >= 10 || (this.esUnaBusquedaDeDispositivos && this.cuentaDispositivos >= 1)
  const sub = this.subTipo.length >= 10 || (this.esUnaBusquedaDeDispositivos && this.subTipo.length >= 1)
  
  return dispositivos || sub ? true : false;
}
```